# How can I see what the request object looks like?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Whenever I try

```
logger.info ("REQUEST: \n " + request.to_yaml)
```

I get this error:

```
can't dump anonymous class Class
```

What's the best way to see what's in the request object (in a readable way)?

Comment: Related?: [can't dump anonymous class Class in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15172540/456814).

Answer (score 5):

```
logger.info ("REQUEST: \n " + request.inspect)
```

Comment: `inspect` munges everything together on one line -- it's impossible to see what's going on

Comment: I guess I'm just used to reading it that way. The problem you are running into is that not every Class defines to_yaml, and specifically "Class" in  the error you're seeing.

You could be more specific though. Is there a reason you need to see the entire request object, and not just some subset of its attributes?