# can't dump anonymous class Class in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

can anyone explain what this exception mean in ruby.

> TypeError Exception: can't dump anonymous class Class

Code Sample

```
   Class X_controller
     before filer: validate, :only => [:meth1]
     def meth1
      y.new.send_later(:issue1) #throws me exception
     end
     def meth2
      y.new.send_later(:issue1) #works
     end
     private
     def valiadate
      y.new.send_later(:issue1) #throws me exception
     end
    end
    class y
     include x::z
     def issue1
     end

    end
    module x::z
     def send_later(meth,*args)
     end
    end
```

Comment: This seems to be a problem that was already fixed in my version of Rails. What version are you using?

Comment: @alestanis rails 2.3.8

Comment: Have you considered moving to Rails 3?

Comment: yes but not now so i need some kind of fix what is the actual issue i am still not able to understand

Comment: This is either caused by what I wrote on my answer, or just a bug on older Rails versions. Looking at your code this seems like a Rails bug to me, that's why I suggest you upgrade...

Comment: Related?: [How can I see what the request object looks like?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1351968/456814).

Answer (score 7):

This happens when you try to call `to_yaml` or `to_json` or any other representation directly on a class instead of calling it on an instance. For example

```
User.to_json
```

will dump, but

```
user = User.first
user.to_json
```

will work just fine.

**EDIT:**

This problem seems to also be a bug in older Rails versions, that was fixed for (at least) Rails 3.